# Make external SSD appear in Finder

Tags: finder, disk-utility, ssd, apple-silicon, diskutil

I bought a new external SSD, but when I connected it to my MBP (14" 2021 Ventura 13.0.1, Apple M1 Pro), it did not show up in the Finder (sidebar or anywhere else).

How I can make it show up?

What I did so far:
I googled around a bit and was suggested to use disk utility. Indeed, the SSD showed up there in ExFAT format. However, first aid and erase (for reformatting) failed with error messages. So I resorted to terminal. When I typed `diskutil list`, I saw:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         994.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +994.7 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.7 GB    disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 11.7 GB    disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 9.4 GB     disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.5 GB     disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    596.8 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s6

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.8 TB    disk4
   1:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk4s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data SSD                     16.8 TB    disk4s2
```

So I guess the `disk4` was my external SSD (16TB). For reformatting, I then typed `diskutil eraseDisk MS-DOS SSD /dev/disk4`, which got me

```
Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69760: Unable to write to the last block of the device
```

Apparently an error (which I don't really understand). But my `diskutil list` now looked like:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         994.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +994.7 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.7 GB    disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 11.7 GB    disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 9.4 GB     disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.5 GB     disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    596.8 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s6

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *16.8 TB    disk4
```

And the disk now shows up in disk utility as "FSS SSD Media, not initialised". So something seems to have changed indeed. I then also tried running `diskutil eraseDisk APFS SSD /dev/disk4` for a better format, which got me the same error message as above. I then mounted the disk using `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk4`, which gave me `Volume(s) mounted successfully`, but still the disk does not show up in finder.

`diskutil info /dev/disk4` shows:

```
Device Identifier:         disk4
   Device Node:               /dev/disk4
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk4
   Device / Media Name:       SSD

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       None
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Allgemein
   Protocol:                  USB
   SMART Status:              Not Supported

   Disk Size:                 16.8 TB (16777216000000 Bytes) (exactly 32768000000 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes

   Media OS Use Only:         No
   Media Read-Only:           No
   Volume Read-Only:          Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:           External
   Removable Media:           Fixed

   Solid State:               Info not available
   Virtual:                   No
```

**How can I make the disk show up in finder and use it?**

Comment: Crucial information missing: brand and model of the external drive. It does not appear because it has no filesystem to mount! `Mounted: Not applicable (no file system)`

Comment: A big red flag is a **16TB** SSD. If it cost less than $1,000 it is more than likely a fake. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/01/64gb-microsd-cards-are-posing-as-16tb-portable-ssds-on-amazon/

Comment: I think @Tetsujin is a bit too generous with the pricing!  I just checked and a Western Digital external 16TB enclosure is $4,300 USD.  Unless the OP spent some big bugs on that drive, it’s definitely a fake and unlikely to ever be functional!

Comment: Ok yeah you're probably right. The disk came without a brand and cost me 60 Bucks on an online marketplace. It was apparently too good to be true... But thanks for your comments anyway.

Comment: Send it back, report the seller to whoever runs the marketplace. Got to try shut these scammers down one at a time.